Do we ever see the dangers of violating the Prime Directive?
There seem to be several episodes across the Star Trek canon which deal with the Prime Directive, but they nearly always seem to be kind of subversions - i.e. the characters must decide between obeying the Prime Directive and "doing the right thing" as it were.
This really makes the Prime Directive look like a bureaucratic obstacle, designed to hold the characters back from saving lives, rather than the righteous guiding principle it's made out to be by the various captains (especially Picard & Janeway).
But are there any episodes which show the Prime Directive as a good thing? - e.g. showing the consequences of violating it, despite being well-intentioned, as a negative?
The closest one I can think of is Voyager: Time and Again

 wherein the crew accidentally wipe out an entire population (don't worry - it's a time travel episode - they get better), but because the circumstances of the disaster are specific to time-travel and an accident with a sci-fi nuclear power station...

...rather than being an example of the revealing aliens or interfering with a less advanced culture causing problems or social upheaval, I'd exclude this.

Remember when somebody dropped a book about gangsters on a primitive planet and when they came back it was worldwide Guys and Dolls?

There is quite an extensive list of references to the Prime Directive on the Wikipedia article, including several examples where violating the Prime Directive had negative effects. But it's also worth noting the Prime Directive is not solely about avoiding potential negative effects of interference. Even if they were 100% sure interference would be "beneficial" (according to whom, first of all) it's not the Federation's responsibility to try to change the natural development of civilizations.

@shim is correct. The point is not to prevent negative effects, it’s to prevent any effects.

Star Trek: Voyager - 7x21 "Friendship One" would be the example of what can go wrong. Though, Friendship 1 was started before the Federation, it still had catastrophic effects on a civilization which had not reached this level of technology yet.

@DougWarren I just watched that episode this week, and it ends up with Bones admitting that he left his communicator on the planet.  Which they never even try and retrieve.  Kirk just doesn't care about the Prime Directive /s

I'd think the real life examples of "cargo cults", not to mention what Europeans did to the Americas, would serve as good examples of why TPD is a Good Idea.

Re: samples of high-tech stuff left behind causing problems, John Campbell addressed the issue in his editorial for Analog called No Copying Allowed", November 1948.  He posits a drone that gets sent back in time only a few years, from his time to ca 1920.  The best minds of the time, scientists and engineers, are completely at a loss--the device seems to have no engine, just a tube, and the control surfaces are impossible.  The doped silicon avionics are too pure to be detected, etc, etc.  And that is only 28 years! Ironically, some of the young engineers might go on to develop the drone...

"Who Watches the Watchers" may be the best example - a misstep by the Next Generation Enterprise crew leads to a resurgence of religious belief in a society that had lost that belief in previous centuries,  which is certainly a major impact.
Strangely, The Orville has a better example of what you're looking for, in the story of Gendel 3, a planet that was given technology it wasn't ready for, resulting in disaster.

In 2235, Gendel 3 had a thriving level of industrialization, achieved
nearly 200 years before that of Sargus 4. In this year, early
Planetary Union explorers, acting as missionaries, arrived on Gendel
3. These explorers found a divided world, bristling with nuclear weapons and continents sliced up by national borders. They landed and
revealed both themselves and their technology, providing it to the
world in the hope that it could allow the civilization to skip the
growing pains gone through by similar worlds. The spread, however, was
rapid and the various nation-states battled, with wars breaking out
everywhere, leaders hoping to use the advanced technology for personal
gain and political dominance. Within five years, the entire population
of 9 billion people was wiped out, those few remaining heavily
mutated, diseased, and living ferally.


Nice shift over to Orville, which is Star Trek in all but name.

"entire population of 9 billion people was wiped out, those few remaining"  better as "nearly the entire population of 9 billion people was wiped out, those few remaining"

@chux-ReinstateMonica That would need to be fixed in the source wiki, not (only) in this answer.

Ironically The Orville also did the "accidentally founding a religion" story arguably better, in "Mad Idolatry". The first three quarters or so of that episode would also be a pretty decent argument in favor of non-interference (but the last quarter-ish completely counteracts that).

In "Patterns of Force" from The Original Series, Professor John Gill is supposed to be an observer on Ekos.  He violates the Prime Directive though and introduces a version of Nazism with himself as the leader as a way of helping raise the standard of living for the people.  While it seems to work in the short run,  it unfortunately fails in the longer term.  At the end a dying Gill tells Kirk he was wrong and non-interference is the only way.

I think it could be argued that for one of the two planets in the system, it works quite well with no apparent down-side. The down-side arises from the conflict created with their sister planet, whose citizens are experiencing all the downside. The altered culture is not itself a victim of interference but an evolving threat and thus unwelcome to anyone and everyone they might encounter.

"it works quite well with no apparent down-side." You don't count turning an entire planet full of people into xenophobic, racist killers as a downside?  You don't count the rule of a tyranical dictator as a downside?

@JRE The word you're looking for is "Externalities" and now you know why it's important to extremely side-eye anyone who uses it cavalierly.

John Gill only interfered on the one planet.  No mention of him doing anything on the sister planet.  Those people were also trying to help Ekos and no mention made of Gill being on it or doing anything to interfer with it.

"Non-interference is the only way!" Gill, you didn't prove outside interference was bad, you proved Nazism was bad, and most of us knew that already.

Insurrection comes to mind. Starfleet high command argues that the Prime Directive doesn't apply, and they do have half a point, but their interference with the Ba'ku definitely has/would have had, devastating consequences. Picard's main reason for going against his orders is what he sees as a violation of the Prime Directive by the rest of Starfleet.

We see the motivation and possibly the origin of the Prime Directive in the ST:Enterprise episode "The Communicator".
Archer and crew find that they have "contaminated" a WW2-era planet by accidentally leaving a communicator behind to be discovered by the locals.  When they try to retrieve it, the "contamination" gets progressively worse.  They're captured and interrogated by the military of one of two great nations on the brink of war, which concludes that they're enemy spies.  In the process of making an escape, they reveal even more of their technology.  At the end, Archer reflects that they've almost certainly pushed the two nations closer to war, by making one of them think the other has secret advanced weapons.  He concludes that the nascent Earth starfleet ought to come up with "some kind of directive" to guide starship captains and prevent this kind of thing in the future.

Leaving the communicator behind was a gag at the end of “A Piece of the Action,” which I’m amazed hasn’t come up in an answer already.

The Prime Directive serves at least a couple of purposes in Star Trek stories. For one thing, it provides a source of conflict to drive a story forward, usually because either ship and/or crew or the society involved are under some threat if events are allowed to play out without interference, and there are likely adverse consequences if any intervention is attempted. For another, it serves to reflect on our own history in which cultures at differing levels of technological development have interacted e.g. Renaissance Europe in the New World and the Pacific, and the proxy conflicts between the US and Soviet Union in Korea and Vietnam.
We almost never see the long-term impact of interference, typically because stories are episodic and play out over a time scale of days or weeks, and true long-term impacts would only become apparent after years or decades.
One example which illustrates the impact of inadvertent interference is the ST:Voyager episode "Blink of an Eye" in which, because of time dilation, we see the effect of Voyager's appearance in a planet's night sky for what on the surface is centuries but aboard ship is no more than a few hours.

Star Trek: The Next Generation, season three, episode four, "Who Watches the Watchers", shows the Enterprise's crew experiencing Prime Directive troubles when the accidental exposure of a federation research station ends up with one of the Bronze Age locals mistaking Picard for a god.

@StanleyWebb Yes, but I think OP's question was about long-term impact;. We see the immediate effect, but we don't see the long-term effect on the planet's cultural evolution. Similarly, we see the impact of the Horizon on the inhabitants of Sigma Iota II (1920s gangster culture) in TOS: "A Piece of the Action", but we never see the long term effect of the Enterprise crew's attempt to "fix" it.

The existence of the Prime Directive also provides an in-universe reason why the primitive planets aren't "brought up to speed" routinely by telling them all about space travel, giving them high tech, enlightened government, and everything else -- they're "allowed" to remain at whatever level of development they're at for the story purposes. Without that plot device, the question why the Federation doesn't just come in & provide modern medicine (and modern everything else) to make the natives' lives better would be a significant plot hole in many cases.

@RalphJ Funny thing is how the Federation bends the rule in TOS:"Friday's Child" in which the Enterprise is sent to Capella IV to negotiate mining rights in exchange for access to certain Federation resources including modern medicine (in competition against a Klingon emissary).

Although the Federation didn't start it, there's a clear example of what can go wrong with giving technology in TOS 2x16 "A Private Little War". Klingons supply one faction on a primitive world with weapons, encouraging them to wage war on the neighbors they used to live in peace with. Unwilling to leave them defenseless, the Federation's response is to arm those neighbors in turn, but they know that it will inevitably lead to further escalations and bad blood in the future. Their faction won't be slaughtered by the Klingon-armed faction any more, but the war will be costly, and in general it would have been better for everyone if both the Klingons and Federation had just stayed out of it.

In Strange New Worlds Season 1, Episode 1, "Strange New Worlds", the crew of the Enterprise encounter a planet that had used their astronomy telescopes to observe phenomena caused by the USS Discovery nearby. From these observations, they figured out matter/antimatter reactions and invented what were essentially warp bombs far before they had resolved their differences as a species, putting them at risk of an equivalent of Earth's World War III, but with much more destructive weapons. Only Captain Pike's warning and story of how humanity almost ended itself pushed the inhabitants of Kiley 279 to seek peace rather than final violent solutions to their problems.
Side Note: The Prime Directive was only called General Order 1 prior to the events on Kiley 279. General Order 1 was renamed to the Prime Directive in the aftermath of those events, to reinforce its paramount importance.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  So is that a danger?  It seems that the intervention prevented a disaster.

@DavidW They were just undoing the problem caused by Discovery earlier. While not an intentional interference, it still interfered with the planet's normal development.

I'd echo Barmar, @DavidW. Making the warp phenomena observable to Kiley 279's scientists and engineers violated the Prime Directive. This violation led to interference in Kiley 279's normal development with their development of warp bombs from their observations. A second intervention was determined to be necessary to prevent the likely outcome of the first intervention - that being global antimatter annihilation/omnicide. In fact, at the time of the events on Kiley 279, the Prime Directive was only called General Order 1. GO1 was renamed to the Prime Directive because of these events.

There are many of these in TOS, because the production team tried to keep costs down by re-using existing sets and costumes.  A couple of the most significant that haven’t been mentioned so far: Sometimes this was played very seriously (“The City on the Edge of Forever” is about a dilemma with what Trek would later call the Temporal Prime Directive).  Other times, it was just played straight.  In “A Piece of the Action,” a single contact a hundred years ago (in-universe, before there was a Prime Directive) left behind a book, published on Earth in 1992, Chicago Mobs of the Twenties, which has become the planet’s holy book.  Their entire culture has been replaced by an imitation of it.  Similarly, in “Bread and Circuses,” First Citizen Mericus is really Captain Merik, who went missing six years earlier (although this is not the reason the planet is ruled by a Roman Empire that never fell and has twentieth-century technology, mainly gladiator fights on live TV).
A tragic rather than comic case of well-intentioned cultural exchange gone wrong from the same period was from “Enterprise: Cogenitor.” (Although the Prime Directive didn’t exist yet and the Vissians were warp-capable, which means the Prime Directive would not have applied to them in the Twenty-Fourth Century anyway). Their first contact with the Federation led to Trip Tucker attempting to rescue a Vissian who was being mistreated, causing a diplomatic incident.  When this failed, the Vissian committed suicide rather than go back to the only life their own culture would allow.

About "A Piece of the Action", actually, Kirk himself comments on the Horizon's visit being before the Prime Directive, in the turbolift to Spock and McCoy (~01:57).  This was before beaming down, but after Kirk discusses things with Boss Oxmyx (and promises to explain things to Oxmyx).  The Horizon also left a variety of technical books.

@DavidG. Thank you for the correction!

The 13th episode of the first season of the children's animated series Star Trek: Prodigy involves a society harmed by a first contact which violated the Prime Directive. In fact the cultural distinctiveness of the 'Enterpriseans' appears to have been entirely supplanted by a cargo cult of the ST:TOS crew and history. The nature of the first contact created a local hazard which caused culturally transmitted fear, in part through a geographic taboo, and a disease which is described as killing Enterpriseans across their history since first contact, and is show to be harming at least one Enterprisean during the events of the episode.
